# Error In Wordpress On All Pages Just Below The Header (Using Theme elumine)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-fonts

The error is in below lines of the addressed file below (Line 186 & 187):

Website (Live): [www.healthyminds.world](http://www.healthyminds.world)

Tried restoring an earlier back-up(24 hours back), but that didn't work also.

Line 186 & 187 from source line:

```
$collections = get_option('google_typography_collections');
$google_fonts_all = $this->get_fonts();
$import_fonts = array();
if ($collections) {
    foreach ($collections as $collection) {
        $font_family = $collection['font_family'];
        $font_index = array_search($font_family,
                              array_column($google_fonts_all,'family'));//Line 186
        $font_variants = implode(',', $google_fonts_all[$font_index ['variants']); //Line 187
                array_push(
                    $import_fonts,
                    array(
                        'font_family' => $collection['font_family'],
                        'font_variant' => $font_variants,
```

Error Messages (On All Pages Of Website, **these are just few of the lines**):

```
content/themes/elumine/includes/integrations/google-typography/google-typography.php on line 186

Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/customer/www/healthyminds.world/public_html/wp-content/themes/elumine/includes/integrations/google-typography/google-typography.php on line 186

Warning: Illegal string offset 'variants' in /home/customer/www/healthyminds.world/public_html/wp-content/themes/elumine/includes/integrations/google-typography/google-typography.php on line 187

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/customer/www/healthyminds.world/public_html/wp-content/themes/elumine/includes/integrations/google-typography/google-typography.php on line 187
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the errors because on line 186 the $google_fonts_all either does not contain an array with 'family' key or it is not an array. In either case the expression, array_column($google_fonts_all, 'family'), returns empty.

You can extract the later expression into a variable:
$family = array_column((array)$google_fonts_all, 'family');

On the line 187, check for the isset( $google_fonts_all[$font_index]['variants'] ) either in a conditional statement or itenary.

Regards
Eliasu

Answer (score 0):

Wisdom Labs has posted a [patch](https://wisdmlabs.com/docs/article/wisdm-elumine-theme/tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-google-typography-limit-exceeded-error/) to fix the problem.